# failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 525

Tags: javascript, socket.io

So i recently switch to having SSL through cloudflare and have it set to flexible and I haven't been able to connect to my socket i was getting a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but then i added

```
var connectionOptions =  {
    "force new connection" : true,
    "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", //avoid having user reconnect manually in order to prevent dead clients after a server restart
    "timeout" : 10000, //before connect_error and connect_timeout are emitted.
    "transports" : ["websocket"],
    "secure" : true
};

SOCKET = io('wss://my_site:8443', connectionOptions);
```

and that got rid of the Allow Origin error but now im getting

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_site:8443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 525
```

My backend code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8443);

io.set('transports', [ 'websocket' ]);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //...
});
```

Comment: Looks like an SSL problem: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200278659-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed

Comment: i wasn't thinking that because that article says only for full or full (strict) and i have it on flexible because with it on full my site doesn't load at all and gets error 521. But i tried connecting through my servers IP and im getting

`failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` and my socket server is up